# SSL certificate is working, but New Relic pinging can't detect it

Tags: ssl, heroku, newrelic

I'm getting errors from my New Relic availability monitor, but my SSL Cert seems to be working fine from my machine and according to SSL report (see image)

Here's the error from New Relic: 
`<domain-name> (connection error (Received fatal alert: internal_error))`

The New Relic availabilty monitor works for the Heroku subdomain that this other domain points to.

Here's the SSL report. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was just a problem with my DNS or heroku. New Relic is now pinging properly:

[image]